# Serial port coin acceptor reading

Tags: c#, serial-port

```
private void serialPort1_PinChanged(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e) 
{
     time = time + 100;
}
```

I've made a cafe program in C# which reads pulse from SerialPort and adds time to user. Also there is an electronic circuit connected between coin acceptor and serial port. I'm using the code above to read pulse from coin acceptor.

Code works fine and catches pin changes very well. But there is one problem: The pinchanged function works twice. Normally it must add 100 to time variable, but it adds 200 every time. Why this happens?

Comment: Maybe because the pulse is counted twice as a change, ie going high, then going low. Either add 50 per change or flip a true false variable and test on true to add 100.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, the event is call one time when the pig goes up (Low to High) and one when it goes down (High to Low), so you have +200.